# How to set a dynamic loginUrl in yii. Wildcard in the url?

Tags: php, yii

In my urlManager I have the following rules:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules'     => array(
        '/<slug>/<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
        '/<slug>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '/<slug>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

So I need the the loginUrl to be set to redirect to a dynamic url:

```
'user' => array(
    'class'          => 'WebUser',
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    'loginUrl'       => array( '/<slug>/admin/login' ),
),
```

How can I redirect to a dynamic url such as `/test1/admin/login` and `/test2/admin/login` no just `/admin/login`, `/*/admin/login` I need a wildcard in the url? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you put below code to components/controller.php as ,

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
        if (!isset($_GET['slug'])) {
            $url = CMap::mergeArray(array(Yii::app()->controller->id . '/' . Yii::app()->controller->action->id, 'slug' => 'test1'), $_GET);
            $this->redirect($url);
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

and below code to config/main.php as

```
'rules' => array(
                ---
                    '/<slug>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

                    '/<slug>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that like this:

```
class Test1Module extends WebModule {

class Test2Module extends WebModule {
```

Parent Class is like this:

```
class WebModule extends CWebModule {

public function init() {
   $slug = $this->getId();
   Yii::app()->user->loginUrl = $slug.'/admin/login';
}
....
```

Now you can use UrlManager to direct to place you want

```
 '/<slug>/admin/login>'=>'admin/login',
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks but I need this to be completely dynamic, so I cannot create modules as required.